# The params of c++ function

Tags: c++, variables, reference

The c function with param such as :

```
void test(int fp, int &pos){ //do something... }
```

But i don't understand what does "int &pos" meant .
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: That isn't C, it is probably C++.

Comment: Doesn't that mean pass the int by reference?

Comment: It means that when you call this function, you pass this parameter **by reference** and not **by value**. In other words, instead of creating **a copy** of the variable (or constant value) that you pass to the function, you pass **the address** of that variable (and you cannot pass a constant value because it doesn't have an address in memory). You can then change this variable inside the function, and affect its value **outside** the function (which is not the case when you pass it by value). BTW, this is valid C++ syntax, not C.

Answer (score 1):

It means that pos is made a reference variable to the variable being passed during function call(their address becomes the same).ie, any change in pos reflects in the calling variable.For example :

If function call

```
  test(f,p);
```

changes made to pos will reflect in p.